# Raise an event in VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I need to transform the following in VB.NET from C# (.NET 4)

```
class XXX:

public event EventHandler ContentScaleChanged;

if (otherXXX.ContentScaleChanged != null)
{
    otherXXX.ContentScaleChanged(c, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

please help

EDIT:
I cant' do `RaiseEvent ContentScaleChanged(c, EventArgs.Empty)`, because I need to raise that event on the **`otherXXX`** instance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: My mistake

```
RaiseEvent ContentScaleChanged(c, EventArgs.Empty)
```

RaiseEvent does a null check

If you want to invoke this event handler from another location then the class the event was created in then you need a method to raise the event:

```
Public Sub RaiseContentScaleChanged()
   RaiseEvent ContentScaleChanged(c, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```

Comment: this does not work, because in VB you should use RaiseEvents keyword, and the automation tool can't detect if this is an event of method call...

Comment: I don't raise the Class Event, but the **otherXXX** event!

Comment: Why don't you create a method that raises it?

Comment: humm... because C# code does not contain a ad-hoc method for this... I didn't thought... But hm.... should I create a public method on the class to raise an envent... hmm

Comment: It can be private if invoked from the same class. But in C# you cannot raise an event directly unless you are in the class. So if you want to invoke it from somewhere else you need a method anyway.

Comment: ok. Could you add this information in the answer in order I make it as answer? thanks!

Comment: @moldovanu I have amended the answer